# Unable to get basic svelte-easy-crop example to work

Tags: svelte, crop

I am trying to use the svelte-easy-crop library but I can't get it to work.

I am trying to use the extreme basic functionality as suggested in the readme:

```
<script>
  import Cropper from 'svelte-easy-crop'

  let image = '/images/dog.jpeg'
  let crop = { x: 0, y: 0 }
  let zoom = 1
</script>

<Cropper
 {image}
 bind:crop
 bind:zoom
 on:cropcomplete={e => console.log(e.detail)}
/>
```

All that shows up is a grey square with a white pixel in the middle.

I have tried the following:

- Downgrading svelte to 3.54.0
- Using different images
- putting it inside a wrapper container
- tried to get it to work in a REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/0b047f7d71634bc2b5fcd56d80488c42?version=4.2.0

No errors show up in the console so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The image you're using returns a 503, changing the image URL made your REPL work fine.

Comment: That was it... *facepalm*